# Reliable way to complete operations over ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to save some amount of data when `Activity` is paused. I'm using my own `ContentProvider` backed with SQLite database.

Let's say, that method that perfoms actual saving looks like this:

```
public void saveData() {
    //perform operations over ContentProvider in current thread
}
```

**Question is**: is it safe to just call this method in `onPause` (using new thread)?

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            saveData();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Or should I start a new `Service` that will complete this work in background? Or maybe there is even more reliable way to be sure that data is saved?

Comment: As long as Thread terminates in a finite time, I don't see a problem with that. However, subsequent SQLite operations will block for that period, so very quick pause-resume scenarios will lag a little.

Comment: @User117 problem is that I'm not sure what can I call "finite". So, let's say that thread will terminate in an unpredictable time.

Comment: Consider using asyncTask. Starting new thread takes more time.

Comment: Then, I would recommend providing the user with a Save button, with a progress bar, because Android expects user navigation to be honored within 5 seconds.

Comment: @User117 this is what I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: @Leonidos not sure how start-up time of Thread is significant here

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev I'm not telling you that it's significant. But AsyncTask is lightest way to do short background job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using a bound, background service (better, wrap you Content Provider by one). This will  make it independent of Activity state, just post a get/save request to your Provider Service anytime you want.

Comment: What did you meant by "make your ContentProvider into one"?

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev oh.. you can't extend `Service` and `ContentProvider` at same time. I mean wrap : extend `Service` and hold a `ContentProvider` object.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe, but I suggest not to use onPause() for this purpose. It called too often (see activity lifecycle documentation). Move it to onStop().

Comment: onStop is not guaranteed to be called. so be careful.

Comment: considering how often onPause is called and the unreliability of onStop, maybe you could consider saving it every time new data is generated/modified?

Comment: In my case `onPause` won't be called often. I'm using single Activity with bunch of Fragments.

Comment: Starting on Honeycomb onStop() is guaranteed to be invoked. So, if you don't support earlier version this is way to go. If not, anyway you should consider not to do this staff in onResume().